# nuget download resource failed when docker compose build

Tags: docker

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QP4XW.png)

When I use docker compose build the .net core project '[eShopOnContainers](https://github.com/dotnet-architecture/eShopOnContainers)',The error shows that nuget can't donwload resource.I separately visited the address in my brower it is ok，what cause this error I have no idea，Is any body encountered the same problem？My Environment：windows10 pro,Wsl2,Ubuntu,docker desktop.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZZD8K.png)

Comment: Why are you passing --no-restore to the publish command? What commands are preceding it? If you could post a more lengthy Docker Build output, that would help.

Comment: I just try to build the demo .